# My element not displaying expected value feet converted to inches

Tags: xml, xslt

I have edited my xml code to include `<HeightInches>5</HeightInches>`. I want to convert the HeightFeet number into inches. 
I also want to check that the HeightInches is not less than 48 inches and not greater than 95 inches. 
How do I do this?
**My xml code**

```
<Party ID="1116666" InternalPartyID="1610656384">
    <Gender Word="F">Female</Gender>
    <HeightFeet>5</HeightFeet>
    <HeightInches>5</HeightInches>
    <WeightPounds>130</WeightPounds>
    <EyeColor Word="BLU">Blue</EyeColor>
</Party>
```

**Based on this xml code, desired output should look like this:**

```
<nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
<nc:MeasureText>60</nc:MeasureText>
<nc:MeasureUnitText>inches</nc:MeasureUnitText>
<nc:LengthUnitCode>INH</nc:LengthUnitCode>
```

**The output my xslt is producing looks like this**

```
<nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
<nc:MeasureText>NaN</nc:MeasureText>
<nc:MeasureUnitText>inches</nc:MeasureUnitText>
<nc:LengthUnitCode>INH</nc:LengthUnitCode>
```

**My xslt code**

```
    <nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
   <nc:MeasureText>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="HeightFeet"> 
       <xsl:value-of select="(HeightFeet*12) + HeightInches "/>
    </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
   </nc:MeasureText>
   <nc:MeasureUnitText>
      <xsl:text>inches</xsl:text>
   </nc:MeasureUnitText>
   <nc:LengthUnitCode>
   <xsl:text>INH</xsl:text>
   </nc:LengthUnitCode>
</nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? Please edit your post with complete XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Your context node is not known based the xslt you are showing. So it could be a number of reasons your code does not work. Its possible your context is not correct. Nevertheless its always good to cast (easier to ready). I believe some xslt 2.0 processors require this.

```
<xsl:value-of select="(number(HeightFeet)*12) + number(HeightInches) "/>
```

**EDIT**

Also, your input xml does not have the element `HeightInches` which will give you a `NaN` when you try to multiple a value that does not exist.

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Well, if there's no HeightInches value, then converting it a number will not help. OTOH if the value exists, then converting it to a number will not achieve anything.

Comment: I agree. I was able to reproduce the problem in 1.0 because the value does not exist. Casting a number is however a good practice.

Comment: "*Casting a number is however a good practice.*" Our opinions on that differ.

Comment: Perhaps we can discuss in a chat session. I am interested in your opinion.

Comment: Sorry, can't take the time. Wouldn't have much to add anyway. If the value is castable as number, then you can multiply it without conversion. If it's not, then conversion will not help. You need conversion when (and only when) the type can be misinterpreted: for example, when placing a string of digits inside a positional predicate.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did in the xslt and it is now producing the desired output converting HeightFeet into HeightInches and checking if the HeightInches is less than 45 inches or equal or greater than 95 inches.

```
<xsl:variable name="vHeightInches">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="HeightInches">
            <xsl:value-of select="HeightInches"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vHeightFeet">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="HeightFeet">
                <xsl:value-of select="HeightFeet"/>
            </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="(($vHeightFeet*12) + $vHeightInches &gt; 48) and (($vHeightFeet*12) + $vHeightInches &lt; 95)">
    <nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
        <nc:MeasureText>
            <xsl:value-of select="($vHeightFeet*12) + $vHeightInches"/>
        </nc:MeasureText>
        <nc:MeasureUnitText>
            <xsl:text>inches</xsl:text>
        </nc:MeasureUnitText>
        <nc:LengthUnitCode>
            <xsl:text>INH</xsl:text>
        </nc:LengthUnitCode>
    </nc:PersonHeightMeasure>
</xsl:if>
```

`